# Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way in jQuery to get all CSS from an existing element and apply it to another without listing them all?

I know it would work if they were a style attribute with `attr()`, but all of my styles are in an external style sheet.

Answer (score 345, accepted):

A couple years late, but here is a solution that retrieves both inline styling and external styling:

```
function css(a) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, o = {};
    for (var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var r in rules) {
            if (a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {
                o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(a.attr('style')));
            }
        }
    }
    return o;
}

function css2json(css) {
    var s = {};
    if (!css) return s;
    if (css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
        for (var i in css) {
            if ((css[i]).toLowerCase) {
                s[(css[i]).toLowerCase()] = (css[css[i]]);
            }
        }
    } else if (typeof css == "string") {
        css = css.split("; ");
        for (var i in css) {
            var l = css[i].split(": ");
            s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Pass a jQuery object into `css()` and it will return an object, which you can then plug back into jQuery's `$().css()`, ex:

```
var style = css($("#elementToGetAllCSS"));
$("#elementToPutStyleInto").css(style);
```

:)

Comment: BTW, when you say a *JSON object*, you just mean a JavaScript object right?

Comment: +1 Mark, great solution which i've just given credit to in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858042/how-to-tell-if-a-div-is-height-constrained/6858194#6858194) :)

Comment: this looks awesome, but when I'm trying it it misses out on certain properties such as font-family.

Comment: @Damon any clue why? Is it a per-browser issue?

Comment: It's fine actually. I was erroneously expecting inline styles to come with it.

Comment: @Damon: That's a valid assumption, considering the first line of the answer says *...here is a solution that retrieves both **inline styling** and external styling*.

Comment: @Damon it does not miss out on certain properties, inline or not. I just checked on it myself. Could you please provide jsfiddle or gist showing that it does not work? Elsewise it worked just fine.

Comment: My bad. When I said inline I was really talking about inherited styles

Comment: One problem with otherwise great solution is some browsers apply Same Origin Policy and will set `cssRules` to `null`.

Comment: +1, but it seems vulnerable to clobbering styles with higher precedence if they're in the wrong order in a stylesheet. Solving that may be quite complex and probably expensive.

Comment: Just tried using the code, it seemed to trip up giving me this error in chrome: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: button.ui-button::-moz-focus-inner

Comment: "button.ui" does not appear anywhere in this code, so I'm not sure how it could have a syntax error on that? Are you sure it isn't a browser plugin? I can't get the error to happen. Have a JSFiddle?

Comment: This code doesn't work any more (always returns empty object in Chrome)

Comment: Providing a patch/fix or jsFiddle that highlights exactly where your error is happening (if any) would be greatly appreciated - to back up your claim and provide insight for others. Thanks!

Comment: Note: getMatchedCSSRules is currently only implemented in Webkit browsers ( [Compatibility Table](http://compatibility.shwups-cms.ch/en/home/?&property=getMatchedCSSRules) ), so using this in Firefox or IE will cause problems. You'll need a polyfill to handle this code.

Comment: Note: Moderators have modified my original code, I give no guarantee anything will work.

Comment: does this also get css for all descendant elements?

Comment: Note, this does not retrieve the browser default styles, only styles that have been applied by stylesheets or inline.

Comment: Not working for me , I tested in chrome console. it is not working. When i put "var style = css(jQuery('#main input'));" after executing the css() function, i got following error "Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: hover "

Comment: CORS is starting to piss me off with all it's retardedness: You'll get a `Error: The operation is insecure.` if the CSS is from remote site...

Comment: here is a fiddle of my version, which is quite similar, but doesn't choke on psuedo-selectors. also has a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a2f0phg5/1/

Comment: I found this solution craps out if you use @import, any way around that, other than of course not using @import?

Comment: This won't work for HTTPS sites in Chrome due to security policy

Comment: Joining @Mike I want to remind that the solutions above do not copy the hover, active etc. states of the selected items. :-/

Comment: @bencergazda I haven't tried it, but if you need the :hover states you could trigger a mouseover. Not sure if you could get active. Maybe triggering a mousedown? Give it a try.

Comment: This code now causes `Error: The operation is insecure` on firefox (chrome still works).  This is due to `.cssRules` in `var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;`.  You will need try/catch around this line to protect for Firefox.

Comment: Also in firefox I get:
"Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover" Does it take in consideration pseudo classes?

Comment: Facing `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'rules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules` ,
what is the issue ?

Answer (score 92):

Two years late, but I have the solution you're looking for. Not intending to take credit form the [original author](http://upshots.org/?p=192), here's a plugin which I found works exceptionally well for what you need, but gets **all** possible styles in all browsers, even IE.

**Warning:** This code generates a lot of output, and should be used sparingly. It not only copies all standard CSS properties, but also all vendor CSS properties for that browser.

`jquery.getStyleObject.js:`

```
/*
 * getStyleObject Plugin for jQuery JavaScript Library
 * From: http://upshots.org/?p=112
 */

(function($){
    $.fn.getStyleObject = function(){
        var dom = this.get(0);
        var style;
        var returns = {};
        if(window.getComputedStyle){
            var camelize = function(a,b){
                return b.toUpperCase();
            };
            style = window.getComputedStyle(dom, null);
            for(var i = 0, l = style.length; i < l; i++){
                var prop = style[i];
                var camel = prop.replace(/\-([a-z])/g, camelize);
                var val = style.getPropertyValue(prop);
                returns[camel] = val;
            };
            return returns;
        };
        if(style = dom.currentStyle){
            for(var prop in style){
                returns[prop] = style[prop];
            };
            return returns;
        };
        return this.css();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Basic usage is pretty simple, but he's written a function for that as well:

```
$.fn.copyCSS = function(source){
  var styles = $(source).getStyleObject();
  this.css(styles);
}
```

Comment: @Damon: Thanks! I've updated my post, and edited the wording slightly to make it clear that this is not my work. Sorry about the previous wording, I think I typed this answer up late at night, but either way, it was pretty douchey.

Comment: Why does this return `this.css()`? There's no [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for this method taking no arguments, and if this statement is reached, it throws an exception. I think it would be more appropriate to `return returns;` even if it's an empty object.

Comment: Would it be possible to get a working demo of this? Not clear to me where to put this code and how to invoke it.  It's also not clear to me where the output is being stored.  Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand how to use it, There's something called jsfiddle that most people use to help. Good programmer are the worse teacher

Comment: @Gino If you want to copy the style of div1 to div 2 just use: 
**`$("#div2").copyCSS($("#div1"));`** and to get the style of any element you could use: **`JSON.stringify($('#element').getStyleObject());`**

Comment: @Cymro If you want to copy the style of div1 to div 2 just use: 
**`$("#div2").copyCSS($("#div1"));`** and to get the style of any element you could use: **`JSON.stringify($('#element').getStyleObject());`**

Answer (score 18):

Why not use [`.style` of the DOM element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp)?  It's an object which contains members such as `width` and `backgroundColor`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the only way to get the actual styles associated with the class. (as opposed to the calculated styles which are different)

Comment: With .style you only get properties applied to the style attribute of the element, but not those applied with a CSS class.

Comment: +1 as i m using inline script and changing it dynamically afterwords

Answer (score 11):

I had tried many different solutions. This was the only one that worked for me in that it was able to pick up on styles applied at class level and at style as directly attributed on the element. So a font set at css file level and one as a style attribute; it returned the correct font.

It is simple! (Sorry, can't find where I originally found it)

```
//-- html object
var element = htmlObject; //e.g document.getElementById
//-- or jquery object
var element = htmlObject[0]; //e.g $(selector)

var stylearray = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null);
var font = stylearray["font-family"]
```

Alternatively you can list all the style by cycling through the array

```
for (var key in stylearray) {
console.log(key + ': ' + stylearray[key];
}
```

Comment: [In many code samples, getComputedStyle is used from the document.defaultView object. In nearly all cases, this is needless, as getComputedStyle exists on the window object as well. It's likely the defaultView pattern was a combination of folks not wanting to write a testing spec for window and making an API that was also usable in Java.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 4):

@marknadal's solution wasn't grabbing hyphenated properties for me (e.g. `max-width`), but changing the first `for` loop in `css2json()` made it work, and I suspect performs fewer iterations:

```
for (var i = 0; i < css.length; i += 1) {
    s[css[i]] = css.getPropertyValue(css[i]);
}
```

Loops via `length` rather than `in,` retrieves via `getPropertyValue()` rather than `toLowerCase().`